# JasperReports: unrecoverable multipage subreports

Tags: jasper-reports

For example i have Master report that contains several multipage subreports. I want them to be displayed in order that is set in master report (prints the first subreport and then prints second). When i add these subreports into master datail band, they cover each other.

How can i do such thing?

Thank you

Comment: Just a heads up, if you found the solution to your problem, you should add it as an answer, and mark it accepted. Instead of updating your question. This way it is clear as to what the solution you found is for future users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting each subreport in its own detail band?  Or, if you're putting the subs in an array, include another variable like "reportName" or "reportNumber" and group the subreport detail bands by that variable, so each time the variable changes a new group is created for the new subreport.  Doing it that way would also let you put a group header for each subreport which you could then customize with variables and/parameters.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I found the satisfied solution:
i fill all my reports separately, but export them by JRPdfExporter:

```
            List jasList = new ArrayList();
            jasList.add(jp_1);
            jasList.add(jp_2);
            jasList.add(jp_3);
            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasList);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "batch.pdf");
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_CREATING_BATCH_MODE_BOOKMARKS, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.exportReport();
```

They will be ordered in list order and bookmarks will be generated